# About newer DDR 3 RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

Does all the new DDR3 RAM built into laptops sold at the stores nowadays has the ability to overwrite RAM at shutdown or does one have to check by contacting the producer first before buying?
I have read about cold boot attaacks being applied on older DDR3 RAM this is why i am asking.

[nullcon Goa 2015: Cold Boot Attack on DDR2 and DDR3 RAM by Marko Schuba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHq2xG4XJXM)

Comment: I just read the description to the video. Maybe you should look for boards that wipe RAM when the computer is shutdown, so ask board manufacturers. The description says "While many PC mainboards overwrite DDR3 before they are powered off, this is not the case for the board of the ASUS Notebook P53E which was used in our experiments. As a result, memory content could be extracted"

Comment: But who is going to quickly snatch the RAM from your computer after it has been turned off, and read the data off it in the short time they have to do it? And interpret it correctly. It sounds like that would require enormous expertise. Maybe it's easy when you know how but there aren't going to be many people in the world that know how

Comment: That happens when a swat csi team breaks into your home with liquid nitrogen and a setup board specific for reading the ram, they get to your PC within 1 second of your shutdown, dissasemble your computer, remove the ram bring it down to -32*C plug it in to thier special CSI pc board within 1 second and read the last 5% of the data that exists   depending of course on many other factors, tested on the one that held out the longest.  Sounds either like a movie scenario or a college project for boored hackers.  oh wait it IS :-0

Comment: @Psycogeek but do they get thwarted by the motherboard that wipes the RAM after the computer shuts down? And will this woman he involved https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: @Psycogeek In fairness, I don't think it's fair to just mock it as a CSI style scenario.. rather than address it seriously. The OP included a link to a guy that has actually done it, so while in practice the likelyhood of somebody doing it woudl be fantasy, in theory it's very possible and even in practice, so it can be answered as a technical question. That is why I tried to address it first, and then I added that it's unlikely somebody would do it n why it's unlikely. That youtube hacker guy and his co-worker(s) could do that to each other for fun and games!

Comment: Is your question whether the RAM is capable of being overwritten at shutdown, or whether any systems do it by default, or which systems do it by default, or how to setup the system to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question. The answer to your question is "no": No (common) memory will wipe itself on shutdown. Memory doesn't even know what a "shutdown" is. :-)

Clearing memory is a function of the system software. If your operating system (or firmware / BIOS) does it, then it is done on any memory technology.

Any DRAM technology can be attacked like this, and even a clear-on-shutdown wouldn't help much. Systems under that kind of attack will not be shutdown anyway, because a shutdown might wipe encryption keys from memory. So attackers will freeze the memory while the system is running, then just pull the plug.

Comment: In the end of the video the presentaor says that some they were lucky to have chosen a board that would allow those attacks. However it is also possible to first freeze the ram then unplu it plug it into an different machine and extract te contetnt there? I think if. understood the presentation correctly the presentator says at one point that in this particular case nothing exept if the encryption keys were stored in the CPU from the. beginning would help.